# JNI Error when trying Java application on another computer without JDK

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and facing this problem with my first program.

I wrote a simple program that displays a JFrame to allow users to select some parameters then based on it asks some maths question and collects user input as answer an then displays the result. The program works fine on my laptop where I have JDK. Even when I generate .jar file using Eclipse oxygen, the jar file opens with a simple double click on this laptop.

However, when I copy this program to another laptop that already has JRE installed (Version 8, 261) I'm getting

> JNI Error: Check your installation

I tried on two different laptops with the same error. I searched on StackOverflow, google but could not find the answer to this issue.

I made the executable jar file when exporting from eclipse.

Comment: Try to run the program from the command line and check the stacktrace. One common cause for this is that you compiled your code for a later target version than you JRE supports.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It was indeed due to compiler target version issue. I compiled with java 9 and on other compute it was Java 8. By changing compiler version it worked.